# Entity framework select rows with maximum value for one column

Tags: sql, entity-framework

I have table with about 20 columns. I want to get rows with all columns that have maximum "version" column for each ID.

```
ID      | Version | Other data
--------+---------+----------
1       | 1       | text1
1       | 2       | text2
1       | 3       | text3
2       | 1       | text1
3       | 1       | text1
3       | 2       | text2
```

What I want is:

```
ID      | Version | Other data
--------+---------+----------
1       | 3       | text3
2       | 1       | text1
3       | 2       | text2
```

I know how to achieve it in sql. I don't know how to achieve this on entity framework. Especially if I have 20 columns.

Answer (score 1):

```
context.TableName
    .GroupBy(x=>x.ID)
    .Select(x=>new 
    {
        ID = x.Key, 
        row = x.Where(r=>r.Version == x.Max(m=>m.Version)).FirstOrDefault()})
    .Select(x=>new {x.ID, x.row.Version, x.row.OtherData});
```

Comment: I wrote that I have 20 columns. And you are creating new anonymous type. I want original type that have connection to original row to database.

Comment: I created my own but it is very slow
context.TableName.GroupBy(x=> x.ID)
                        .SelectMany(
                            group=>
                                group.Where(
                                    r=> r.version == group.Max(x => x.version))
                                    .Select(r=> r));

Answer (score 0):

I created my own version but it is slow

```
context.TableName.GroupBy(group=> group.recipeID)
                        .SelectMany(
                            group=>
                                group.Where(
                                    r=> r.version == group.Max(x => x.version))
                                    .Select(r=> r));
```